# WebApplicationInitializer Simple Example

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I need a simple example how to use the WebApplicationInitializer. I have seen plenty of sample implementations, but where do I declare that my individual MyVeryIndividualWebApplicationInitializer should be used?

Do I declare this in the pom-file, or whereever?

Answer (score 1):

Since Servlet 3.0, it is possible to create web application without using any xml configuration, precisely web.xml. **WebApplicationInitializer** is an Interface provided by Spring to be implemented in Servlet 3.0+ environments in order to configure the ServletContext programmatically -- as opposed to (or possibly in conjunction with) the traditional web.xml-based approach.

If you are using Spring Boot you can use **SpringBootServletInitializer** which is a handy opinionated WebApplicationInitializer for applications that only have one Spring servlet, and no more than a single filter (which itself is only enabled when Spring Security is detected). If your application is more complicated consider using one of the other WebApplicationInitializers.

Note that a WebApplicationInitializer is only needed if you are building a war file and deploying it. If you prefer to run an embedded container (we do) then you won't need this at all.

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M4/api/org/springframework/boot/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

> Do I declare this in the pom-file, or wherever?

Since WebApplicationInitializer is part of Spring Web MVC, you dont need any explicit declaration in pom file for WebApplicationInitializer.